# How it impacts hibernate if we change foreign key name from database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm working on a legacy application which uses Hibernate and MySQL. In one of my DB tables, I've found duplicate foreign key constraints. Names are like the following:

- FK3EBE45E8C4027E24
- FK3EBE45E8F5ADD75E

Now I want to drop one index and rename another one from database only. Will there be any impact on hibernate functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **No**

There will not be any impact on the Hibernate code. Only when you make changes to the structure of the table - add/remove/rename a column, change the datatype, then there will be an impact as you will have to make changes to the DTO. MySQL Indexes are abstractions for Hibernate. Hibernate doesn't care whether there's an index or not. It will create a query and send to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a constraint will be impact only on automatic schema update (create). Hibernate will try to delete constraint by name and generate an exception. It is not a problem (for Hibernate 5, don't know about other versions), a schema update will not stop.

If you don't use automatic schema update, you will not have any problems.